# Are the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ related specifically to the primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis, mobius-function

This question assumes the following definitions.

---

**(1)** $\quad \psi(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)\qquad\text{(second Chebyshev function)}$

**(2)** $\quad M(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\mu(n)\qquad\text{(Mertens function)}$

---

It seems to be a fairly widely held notion that the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ are related to the primes, but assuming the Riemann Hypothesis (RH) I believe the non-trivial zeta-zeros can be approximated by relationship (4) below as well as relationship (3) below. Whereas $\Lambda(n)$ in (3) below only takes on non-zero values at prime-powers, $\mu(n)$ in (4) below takes on non-zero values at all square-free integers and the magnitude of $\mu(n)$ at the primes is no different than the magnitude of $\mu(n)$ at other square-free integers. The poles of $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ at the non-trivial zeta-zeros are related to $\zeta(s)$ in the denominator and have nothing to do with $\zeta'(s)$ in the numerator.

---

**(3)** $\quad\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=-\underset{X\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{s}{s-1}+s\int_1^X(\psi(x)-x)\, x^{-s-1}\,dx\right)\\$ $\qquad\qquad=-\underset{X\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{s X^{1-s}}{s-1}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^X\Lambda(n)\left(n^{-s}-X^{-s}\right)\right)\,,\quad\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}\quad\text{(assuming RH})$

**(4)** $\quad\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\int\limits_0^\infty M(x)\,x^{-s-1}\,dx=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}\right),\quad \Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}\quad\text{(assuming RH})$

---

Furthermore, there is an explicit formula for $M(x)$ defined in (2) above as well as $\psi(x)$ defined in (1) above, but the zeta-zero terms are a bit simpler in the explicit formula for $\psi(x)$ than in the explicit formula for $M(x)$ as illustrated in (5) and (6) below.

---

**(5)** $\quad\psi_o(x)=x-\sum\limits_\rho\frac{x^\rho}{\rho}-\log(2\,\pi)+\sum\limits_n\frac{x^{-2\,n}}{2\,n}$

**(6)** $\quad M_o(x)=\sum\limits_\rho\frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho\,\zeta'(\rho)}-2+\sum\limits_n\frac{x^{-2\,n}}{(-2\,n)\,\zeta'(-2\,n)}$

---

> **Question**: Are the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ really related *specifically* to the primes, or is it more correct to say they're related to the square-free integers?

Comment: Edited post to say 'specifically' when using 'really.' I did this to make a bit more clear what you mean by 'really.' I am commenting this to make sure you realize this and change it back if you believe my edit obscured your intention, as I am not myself certain what you meant by 'really'.

Comment: **Maybe it will help** if you write down the explicit formula... Do you understand what is the residue of a simple pole ?

Comment: @heepo I don't have any problem with your edits. I'm trying to understand why the non-trivial zeta zeros would be considered to be more closely related to the primes than they are to the square-free integers.

Comment: @reuns I added the explicit formulas to my question above. Admittedly the zeta-zero terms are a bit simpler in the explicit formula for ψ(x) than in the explicit formula for M(x), but I don't understand complex analysis or if there's any difference with respect to the residue of a simple pole in the two explicit formulas.

Comment: The explicit formula for $\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)$ is uniquely defined by the non-trivial zeros, the one for $\sum_{n\le x}\mu(n)$ is not (also the one you wrote is assuming the zeros are simple and it converges only in the sense $\lim_{k\to \infty}\sum_{|Im(\rho)|\le T_k}$ for well-chosen sequence $T_k$), the reason is that $\zeta'/\zeta,1/\zeta$ have the same poles but the former has simple poles of residue $n$ (the multiplicity of the zero)

Comment: I applause your thoroughness. excellent question

Comment: @reuns I don't understand your statement "The explicit formula for $\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)$ is uniquely defined by the non-trivial zeros, the one for $\sum_{n\le x}\mu(n)$ is not". Both explicit formulas involve sums over the trivial zeros as well as the non-trivial zeros, and I believe in both cases the sums over the trivial zeros converge to zero as $x\to\infty$. In the case of $\psi_o(x)$, $\sum\limits_n\frac{x^{-2\,n}}{2\,n}$ simplifies to $-\frac{1}{2}\,\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$. Is this not correct?

Comment: The problem is not the trivial zeros but the $1/\zeta'(\rho)$. You already asked 10 questions about the (imaginary part of the) non-trivial zeros being the Fourier transform of $\sum_n \Lambda(n)n^{-1/2}(\delta(|u|-\log n)$ how can you miss that. And please stop copying all those useless formulas in all your questions, make it 4 lines long, if you can't it means your question is bad.

Comment: @StevenClark primes are a strict subset of squarefree integers, the subset with 1 prime factor.

Comment: another way to see why the natural duality (as @reuns explained) is between primes and non-trivial zeroes and not between square-free integers and nontrivial zeroes is by counting them - as primes are ~$\frac {x}{\log x}$, non-trivial zeroes are ~$T\log T$ while square free integers are ~$x$, so it is obvious that it makes much more sense to loook for a duality between the first two

Comment: @Conrad I posted a question at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3471485 related to your comment.