# Question on approximation of number of non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ with $0<\Im(\rho)\le t$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

The asymptotic growth of $f(x)$ defined in (1) below is $\overset{\text{~}}{f}(x)$ defined in (2) below, and $\overset{\text{~}}{f}(\frac{t}{2 \pi})$ very closely approximates the asymptotic growth of $N(t)$ defined in (3) below (the number of non-trivial zeta zeros with $0<\Im(\rho)\le t$). These relationships are illustrated following the question below.

---

**(1)** $\quad f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\log(n),\quad\zeta'(s)=-\sum\limits_{n}\log(n)\,n^{^-s}\quad\Re(s)>1$

**(2)** $\quad \overset{\text{~}}{f}(x)=x\,(\log (x)-1)+\frac{\log(2 \pi)}{2},\quad f(x)\approx\overset{\text{~}}{f}(x)$

**(3)** $\quad N(t)=\sum\limits_{0<\Im(\rho)\le t}1\approx\overset{\text{~}}{f}(\frac{t}{2 \pi})$

---

It's widely known the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ are closely related to the primes.

---

> **Question**:  Why is the growth of $N(t)$ so closely related to the growth of $f(x)$ where $\zeta′(s)=-s\int_0^\infty f(x)\,x^{-s-1}\,dx$, and how is $N(t)\approx\overset{\text{~}}{f}(\frac{t}{2 \pi})$ related to the primes?

---

The following figure illustrates $f(x)$ in blue and $\overset{\text{~}}{f}(x)$ in orange.

[image: Illustration of f(x) (blue) and f~(x) (orange)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of $f(x)$ (blue) and $\overset{\text{~}}{f}(x)$ (orange)

---

The following figure illustrates a discrete plot of $N(t)-\overset{\text{~}}{f}(\frac{t}{2 \pi})$.

[image: Illustration of N(t)-f~(t/(2 pi))]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of $N(t)-\overset{\text{~}}{f}(\frac{t}{2 \pi})$

Comment: The short version is that due to the functional equation you get a $\log \Gamma(t)$ in the zero-counting integral, which dominates.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the comment. Could you please point me to a definition of the zero-counting integral that you mentioned?

Comment: If $f$ is holomorphic on $V$, and $W \subset V$ is nice (has sufficiently regular boundary), then by the residue theorem, if $f$ has no zeros on $\partial W$, the number of zeros of $f$ in $W$ (counted with multiplicity) is $$N(W) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial W} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz\,.$$ The integrand is meromorphic and has simple poles at the zeros of $f$, and nowhere else, the residue at a zero of $f$ is the multiplicity. Do that for $f = \zeta$ and, say, the region $W = \{ s : -1 < \operatorname{Re} s < 2, 0 < \operatorname{Im} s < T, \lvert s-1\rvert > \varepsilon\}$,

Comment: provided $T$ is not the imaginary part of a zero. The difficult part is estimating the integral over $\operatorname{Im} s = T$. The bottom of the boundary gives a constant, the part on $\sigma = 2$ remains bounded (since $\log \zeta(2 + it)$ remains bounded), and for the part over $\sigma = -1$ you use the functional equation. One part involves $\zeta'(2 - it)/\zeta(2-it)$, which gives a bounded contribution, the other parts can be explicitly evaluated and give the main part of $N(T)$ (you need some properties of $\Gamma$ and $\cot$).

Comment: This is explained in **every book about $\zeta(s)$**. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann#La_fonction_S(T)

Comment: @reuns I wasn't seeing the connection with the log-step counting function $f(x)$ but the $\log\Gamma(t)$ term in the zero-counting integral explains it.