# Question on convergence of an averaging function related to the non-trivial zeta zero counting function

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

This question is related to the non-trivial zeta zero counting function defined in (1) below and its asymptotic defined in (2) below.

---

**(1)** $\quad N(t)=\sum\limits_{0<\Im(\rho)\le t}1$

**(2)** $\quad\overset{\text{~}}{N}(t)=\frac{t}{2 \pi}\left(\log\left(\frac{t}{2 \pi }\right)-1\right)+\frac{\log(2 \pi)}{2},\quad N(t)\approx\overset{\text{~}}{N}(t)$

---

Now consider the averaging function defined in (3) below.

**(3)** $\quad g(K)=\frac{1}{K}\sum\limits_{k=1}^K\left(N\left(\Im\left(\rho_k\right)\right)-\overset{\text{~}}{N}\left(\Im\left(\rho _k\right)\right)\right)$

---

The following figure illustrates a discrete plot of the function $g(K)$ defined in formula (3) above in blue. The horizontal orange line represents $\frac{\log(2 \pi)}{4}$ which was my initial guess for $\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}g(K)$ but the figure illustrates this guess is not quite correct.

---

[image: Illustration of discrete plot of g(K)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of discrete plot of $g(K)$ defined in formula (3) above (blue)

---

<s>**Question**: Does $\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}g(K)$ have a closed form representation? If not, what is the most accurate known estimate for $\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}g(K)$?</s>

---

After posting this question I noticed the following corollary from Montgomery and Vaughn which assumes $N(t)=(N(t^+)+N(t^-))/2$ where $N(t)=\sum\limits_{0<\Im(\rho)<t}1$ and $s(t)=\frac{1}{\pi}\arg\left(\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right)\right)$.

**(4)** $\quad N(t)=\frac{t}{2 \pi}\left(\log\left(\frac{t}{2 \pi}\right)-1\right)+\frac{7}{8}+s(t)+O\left(\frac{1}{t}\right),\quad t\geq 2$

---

This suggests formula (5) below provides a better asymptotic for $N(t)$ defined in formula (1) above than formula (2) above.

**(5)** $\quad\overset{\text{~}}{N}(t)=\frac{t}{2 \pi}\left(\log\left(\frac{t}{2 \pi }\right)-1\right)+\frac{11}{8},\quad N(t)\approx\overset{\text{~}}{N}(t)$

---

The following figure illustrates a discrete plot of the function $g(K)$ defined in formula (3) above using the definitions of $N(t)$ and $\overset{\text{~}}{N}(t)$ defined in formulas (1) and (5) above.

---

[image: Illustration of discrete plot of g(K) based on formulas (1) and (5)]

**Figure (2)**: Discrete plot of $g(K)$ from formula (3) using formulas (1) and (5) for $N(t)$ and $\overset{\text{~}}{N}(t)$

---

> **Question**: Is it true $\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}g(K)=0$ assuming the definitions of $N(t)$ and $\overset{\text{~}}{N}(t)$ in formulas (1) and (5) above?

---

Now consider the $f(n)$ and $a(n)$ functions defined in formulas (6) and (7) below which assume the definitions of $N(t)$ and $\overset{\text{~}}{N}(t)$ in formulas (1) and (5) above and where $g(K)$ illustrated in Figure (2) above corresponds to $g(K)=\frac{1}{K}\sum\limits_{n=1}^K f(n)$.

---

**(6)** $\quad f(n)=N\left(\Im\left(\rho_n\right)\right)-\overset{\text{~}}{N}\left(\Im\left(\rho_n\right)\right)$

**(7)** $\quad a(n)=
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & f(n)>0 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$

---

The first $28$ values of $a(n)$ defined in formula (7) above match the first $28$ values of [OEIS entry A100060](https://oeis.org/A100060), but if it's true $\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}g(K)=0$ then it seems to me $a(n)$ defined in formula (7) above provides more precise information than OEIS entry A100060.

Comment: $$N\left(\Im\left(\rho_k\right)\right) = K$$ 

What does the density of zeros theorem says on 
$$\hat{N}\left(\Im\left(\rho_k\right)\right)$$

Comment: I would have thought that if $(2)$ has the correct constant term, then $g(K)$ should converge to zero. I don't see how it could converge to $\frac{\log2\pi}4$ instead. And the fact that $g(K)$ does seem to converge to $0$ when you use the correct asymptotic behaviour seems to confirm this?

Comment: @joriki My goal was to determine the correct constant term such that $\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}g(K)=0$. My initial guess was $\frac{\log(2 \pi)}{2}$ based on my earlier question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3471485, but this turned out to be incorrect. The way I defined $N(t)$ in formula (1) this should actually have been $\frac{\log(2 \pi)+1}{2}$ which is closer to being correct but still not exact. It appears $\frac{11}{8}$ is even closer to being the correct value for the constant term, but I'm still wondering if it's exactly correct.